# JavaScript number to 32 bit int equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to "convert" a number in JS to its C style int equivalent. For example: 259 -> 0x00000103.

More specifically I need to send an int as a packet across a socket to a C++ application. So on C side I can simply do a C style cast like: `(unsigned int) packet[0];` on the packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are sending it via a plain TCP socket, you will probably be using Buffers when you write to the socket. Buffer has a [writeInt32BE/LE()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writeint32le_value_offset_noassert) method that you can use to write a signed 32-bit integer to a Buffer.

If you need to write the number as an unsigned 32-bit integer instead, you can use [writeUInt32BE/LE()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint32le_offset_noassert).